# VPN access real location issue

Tags: vpn

I'm using a  VPN which works fine, unless when on Firefox a website asks if they can access my location and I click 'Yes' then it reveals my real location.
How is that possible? Is there any way to click Yes with it revealing the VPN location? since some websites don't seem to work properly without a Yes.

Comment: It explains some things, thanks but it doesn't answer how to click yes without it revealing the real location or if using another browser that's not Firefox would help with that

Comment: Use a plugin that spoofs your location.

Comment: You have 2 different questions in one. 1. How does browser location permission work? (that's not a security question and answered by the link above), and 2. How to hide my location when allowing location permission. I propose reducing this question to the latter question.

Comment: What plug in can I use to spoof the location so that when I click yes access my location it show a different location?

Comment: @mentallurg I'd just note that the accepted answer at that link doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @multithr3at3d: The answers in the linked thread DO answer the OP question *How is that possible?*. And the links in the accepted answer points to the Mozilla page where the authors of Firefox explain how Firefox obtains geolocation information which it sends to the server. Thus this clearly answers the question.

Comment: @mentallurg completely agree, just pointing out that it may be a good idea for others to read past the first/accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've disabled it, Firefox enables **WebRTC** by default which can expose your local address behind a VPN, depending upon VPN details.

In any case, check your VPN connections at some diagnostic sites like:

[ipleak.net](https://ipleak.net/)

[perfect-privacy](https://www.perfect-privacy.com/en/tests/dns-leaktest)